# Android: Rotate HitRect on childView of transformed ViewGroup

Tags: android, transform

I have this function on an ImageView

```
override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
    if (isPointInsideView(event.getRawX(), event.getRawY(), this)) {
       doSomething()
    } else {
       doNothing
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event)
}

fun isPointInsideView(x: Float, y: Float, view: View): Boolean {
    val location = IntArray(2)
    view.getLocationOnScreen(location)
    val viewX = location[0]
    val viewY = location[1]

    //point is inside view bounds
    val _rect = Rect(viewX, viewY, viewX + view.getWidth(), viewY + 
         view.getHeight())
   ///rotate/offset _rect here somehow from it's top left (0,0) corner.
    return if (_rect.contains(x.toInt(), y.toInt())){
    true
    } else {
        false
    }
}
```

But, there is a problem. Some of these ImageViews are inside parent Viewgroups that have been rotated. On those instances, the isPointInsideView doesn't accurately get the view position on the screen and ends up being offset by some amount.

I'm not sure how to correct this. Is `getLocationOnScreen()` being thrown off somehow by the rotation transform of the parent ViewGroup?

UPDATE: So changed the function to use _rect.contains instead (Shown in code above now). The hope was that I could then rotate the _rect the appropriate amount by passing rotation down from the parent ViewGroup... Little did I realise, _rect doesn't have a rotation() method.

I've awful at Matrix transforms, but is there something like that I could do?

Answer (score 0):

I called someone for help and got a resolution.

The answer was to look through the documentation to find all the different X and Y coordinates that were available.

In the end, I found getGlobalVisibleRect() which worked a treat and no matrix required! The method looks like this:

```
fun isPointInsideView(x: Float, y: Float): Boolean {
    val _rect = Rect()
    getGlobalVisibleRect(_rect)
    return _rect.contains(x.toInt(), y.toInt())
}
```